# Sort HTML table by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sorting, html-table

I have the following HTML table which I wanted to be sorted by `data-sku=""`

```js
( function() {
        $("table tbody tr").sort(sort_table).appendTo('table tbody');
            function sort_table(a, b) {
            return ($(b).data('sku')) < ($(a).data('sku')) ? 1 : -1;
        }
} )();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="abp-product-42" data-id="42" data-sku="A-04-0002"><td>A-04-0002</tr>
<tr class="abp-product-21" data-id="21" data-sku="A-04-0011"><td>A-04-0011</td></tr>
<tr class="abp-product-391" data-id="391" data-sku="A-02-0008"><td>A-02-0008</td></tr>
<tr class="abp-product-393" data-id="393" data-sku="A-02-0007"><td>A-02-0007</td></tr>
<tr class="abp-product-40" data-id="40" data-sku="A-04-0010"><td>A-03-0010</td></tr>
<tr class="abp-product-390" data-id="390" data-sku="A-03-0003"><td>A-04-0003</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But somehow it doesn't work - what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Comment: but shouldn't be `A-03-0010`above `A-04-0003`?

Comment: Without jquery, I would access tbody children, copy that to an array, `.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))`, remove the original children and insert the children from the array

Comment: @JohnSmith there is a value mismatch, your code is fine

Comment: The data-sku attribute for the last 2 rows are not match with it's cell content.

Comment: @TBA thanks guys! I was thinking im insane. Last but not least, how can I extend the function so it refreshes the function like every 5 seconds to check if the table has changed (product got removed or added) do I do this with an interval?

Comment: @JohnSmith use [window.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

Comment: I've never worked with the `setInterval` but for my understanding I should create the variable `var intervalID = setInterval(mySortfunction, 500,);` and then call the function like this `function mySortfunction() {...` or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will call your function in every 5 seconds like I mentioned in the comment.

```js
window.setInterval(function(){
 sortData();
}, 5000);

function sortData(){
 $("table tbody tr").sort(sort_table).appendTo('table tbody');
            function sort_table(a, b) {
            return ($(b).data('sku')) < ($(a).data('sku')) ? 1 : -1;
        }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="abp-product-42" data-id="42" data-sku="A-04-0002"><td>A-04-0002</tr>
<tr class="abp-product-21" data-id="21" data-sku="A-04-0011"><td>A-04-0011</td></tr>
<tr class="abp-product-391" data-id="391" data-sku="A-02-0008"><td>A-02-0008</td></tr>
<tr class="abp-product-393" data-id="393" data-sku="A-02-0007"><td>A-02-0007</td></tr>
<tr class="abp-product-40" data-id="40" data-sku="A-04-0010"><td>A-04-0010</td></tr>
<tr class="abp-product-390" data-id="390" data-sku="A-03-0003"><td>A-03-0003</td></tr>
<tr class="abp-product-390" data-id="390" data-sku="A-05-0003"><td>A-05-0003</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @JohnSmith no problem, Happy to help you ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine.
Just, The last 2 rows attribute `data-sku` are not match  with it's cell content.

```
<tr class="abp-product-40" data-id="40" data-sku="A-04-0010">
    <td>A-03-0010</td>
</tr>
<tr class="abp-product-390" data-id="390" data-sku="A-03-0003">
    <td>A-04-0003</td>
</tr>
```

```js
(function () {
    function sort_table(a, b) {
        return ($(b).attr('data-sku')) < ($(a).attr('data-sku')) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    $("table tbody tr").sort(sort_table).appendTo('table tbody');
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="abp-product-42" data-id="42" data-sku="A-04-0002">
            <td>A-04-0002
        </tr>
        <tr class="abp-product-21" data-id="21" data-sku="A-04-0011">
            <td>A-04-0011</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="abp-product-391" data-id="391" data-sku="A-02-0008">
            <td>A-02-0008</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="abp-product-393" data-id="393" data-sku="A-02-0007">
            <td>A-02-0007</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="abp-product-40" data-id="40" data-sku="A-03-0010">
            <td>A-03-0010</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="abp-product-390" data-id="390" data-sku="A-04-0003">
            <td>A-04-0003</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```